# Microsoft Word - Table Cells with background colour reduce thickness of borders

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, text-formatting, table-styles

When I create a table in Microsoft word and format a particular column with a background colour I have noticed that if I save / print to PDF those table cells have an incorrect border thickness.

[PDF Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7DMw.png)

In Word it looks fine.

[Word View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Ygn.png)

I've tried adjusting the cell margins and I am adding borders and cells spacing to the whole table in one go, so can't see why there would be any difference for columns with a background colour.

If I format the background colour of the column to white then cell borders are correct.

Does anyone have any ideas which settings I can check / adjust to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue in my Word for Office 365 ProPlus.

[image]

The issue seems to be related to the border line weight. I found that it's fine when using 3 pt:

[image]

I think you can send a feedback on the issue according to [How do I give feedback on Microsoft Office?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-do-i-give-feedback-on-microsoft-office-2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11).

I have tested for the issue for many times and I failed to fix it by build-in settings.

Copying and pasting it as picture and editing in Excel Spreadsheet aren't the options.